# Visual studio Code doesn't recognize included directories with c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++

I have just started developing c++ in Visual Studio Code and if I have a single file, for example `main.cpp`, the intellisense works fine and the project compiles but VsCode and g++ seem not to recognize other files in the same directory.
I have a `main.cpp` file and a `person.h` file.

[image]

The configrations under c_cpp_properties.json list all the files and directory in the current one:

```
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
```

But the intellisense does not recognize the file and the compiler throws an error when compiling (g++).

**Edit**:
I have done some more testing and it seems to start showing errors only after the project is built (Ctrl+Shift+B) with G++.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I doubt you can wildcard include directories like this (`**`). You need something like `"${wordspaceFolder}"`.

Comment: I am using it as It was included by default and it also shows it on the schema reference "https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference". Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat FWIW [`c_cpp_properties.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) docs say that `**` for recursive searching is supported for `"includePath"`

Comment: @Brian Interesting. Then my best guess is that it only includes nested directories.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have done more testing and it appears that VSCode recognizes the directory correctly but the problem seems to arise after it's built with G++. When building it fails as it doesn't recognize other files and then VSCode starts signaling the included file as an error